# Waiting for elements by refreshing the empty page Python3

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

There is an empty task column on the page, and i'm trying to refresh the page every 3 seconds to find the tasks and pick it up asap, because it can disappear.

I've tried some explicit wait before, but I actually can't integrate it to my specific needs, because I recently started to study programming

```
import time 
refresh_time_in_seconds = 3
driver.get("URL")
url = driver.current_url
while(True):
    if url == driver.current_url:
        driver.refresh()
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(refresh_time_in_seconds)
```

code above works fine for me, but I can't integrate elements search while refreshing. I need to pick the task if it appear after next page refreshing

Answer (score 0):

I would just add else condition where we can get the task element and then break the loop so that you will have the element ready when you exit the loop as and when the url includes the information.

```
import time 
refresh_time_in_seconds = 3
driver.get("URL")
url = driver.current_url

while(True):
    if url == driver.current_url:
        driver.refresh()
    else: # <== this condition is to get the element and exit the while loop
        # get the element here
       task_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath goes here")
       break
    url = driver.current_url
    time.sleep(refresh_time_in_seconds)
# now you can perform operations on the task
task_ele.click()
```